# O365 example setting fails

Tags: ms-office

I just start to learn new Office 365 API. I'm also not so deep understand server-side programming.  I have VS2013 and all pre-requisites as pointed in the link bellow. Some example with Windows Desktop App worked. But when I get example https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Office-365-APIs-Get-d75d1c8a - it fails during setting up in Service Manager after Sign-In to O365.

The error message - "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property '' appId of resource 'Service Principal' ". This message appear instead permissions in Service Manager. When I press OK - "Sign In" point in Service Manager still there - Authentication Failed.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the existing client id and settings from app.config (or web.config in web project). When I removed the following from App.config in the Office365Api.Demo project, I was able to register the app in my own Azure AD.

```
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="[put here your ClientID]" />
<add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="http://localhost/eb2c041088c22f67fecaffda29528308" />
<add key="ida:AuthorizationUri" value="https://login.windows.net/" />
```